# Javascript почему не работает?

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var data = "{ posX: 384, posY: 128 }";
endPos = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(endPos.posX);
console.log(endPos.posY);
```

Не работает ( В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Неправильные кавычки. `JSON.parse()` имеет строгие правила для входных данных. С такой строкой все выполняется на отлично

```
var data = '{"posX": 384, "posY": 128}';
```

Comment: тут не _неправильные_, а по спецификации - ключи объекта должны быть строками